# Nikah for Christian woman and Muslim man

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, islamic-scholar, christianity, interfaith-marriage

My boyfriend and I have been dating since we were 15. We are now 20 and have only been with each other sexually. He recently converted to Islam and I have been raised Christian. We agree that our children will be Muslim and I have no problems with him practicing his religion. We plan to get married ASAP and I don’t drink or eat pork.  Would our Nikah be valid even if I am an nonchaste Christian woman? And if so, what are the requirements for wali and everything else? Thank you for answering.